# How to move/copy OS to new drive without live boot media?

Tags: rsync, fdisk, gpt

I have only been seriously using Linux for a couple of months; I cannot find a simple solution to copy an OS over to another drive, despite there being hundreds of articles on the topic.

First I tried a straight copy of the root, obviously this was a fail.

Using my rudimentary comprehension I tried the following:

1. Get new SSD, plug in
2. type lsblk
3. see the drive is called sdb (for example)
4. type sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb
5. create a partition with fdisk (sdb1 for example)
6. put GPT on the partition (sdb1) with fdisk
7. copy contents: `sudo rsync -WavxHAX / --exclude={"/media/*"} /media/Rob/3a9142f5-8916-406e-87b0-4ec87d7a3d12/`

(assuming the drive is mounted in media) I may have also skipped a mounting step like:

`sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt`

This was written from memory, the steps were probably tried out of order, such as create `GPT` then format partition to `ext4`; but I couldn't figure it either way. Anyway, the basic concept is outlined above; no extra downloaded programs or live USBs need apply.

Can someone please shed some light as to how I could accomplish this?

Comment: Why can't you use a live USB? In general you can't get a good copy of the system while it is running. You really have to umount the drive that you want to image.

Comment: Hi user1794469, well I've heard it be done, granted odd that seems so obscure to do so, so I'm hoping otherwise.  I see a variety of issues in having to use a USB and needing one on-hand, besides the hassle. Wouldn't I need the same OS on the boot media as the OS I was moving across?

Comment: Note all the hassle you are having. A new install to a prepartitioned gpt SSD takes about 10 minutes or less. Then you restore your data & settings from /home from your backup and reinstall exported list of installed apps from backup. That verifies your backup process includes everything while you still have old drive just in case backup is not complete.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot copy an os while running because of the mounted stuff inside /dev /proc /sys ,

but the ext4 allows us to mount a partition to different mount points,

and also you can bind already mounted folder .

`# create mbr table on new SSD 
printf '%s\n' o w |sudo fdisk /dev/sdb;`

`# create partition on it
printf '%s\n' n p 1 '' '' y w |sudo fdisk /dev/sdb;`

`# write ext4 fs on new partition
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1;`

`# create folder where to bind / (root)
sudo mkdir my_os;`

`# mount new partition
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/;`

`# mount|bind actual system to /mnt
sudo mount --bind / my_os/; # like it will clone / to my_os but excluding sub mountpoints /dev /proc /sys`

`# copy the system
sudo cp -arxpf my_os/* /mnt/;`

`# unmount my_os
sudo umount my_os;`

`# remove created folder my_os
sudo rm -r my_os;`

`# change partition UUID inside new system
oldUUID="6e92d1d9-ca30-42d9-9e14-c749d0f349b5";
newUUID="$(eval $(sudo blkid /dev/sdb1|awk '{print $2}') ; echo $UUID)";`

`# loop over files that contains old UUID replace oldUUID by newUUID 
sudo grep -rl "${oldUUID}" /mnt/{etc,boot} | while read f;do 
    sudo sed -i --follow-symlinks "s/${oldUUID}/${newUUID}/g" "${f}" 
done`

now if you wish to use this as dual boot then you just need to update the grub

`sudo update-grub;`

if you wish to use on other pc then you need to install grub 
 for that hard drive to be able to boot 
 to do so you have two ways :

- first

by installing curent grub to the new hard drive , (a bit risky)

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdb;
sudo update-grub;
# unplug new SSD
sudo grub-install /dev/sda;
sudo update-grub;
```

- second

by chroot into the SSD and install its grub , update it from there !

```
# mount SSD in not mounted to /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/; 
# prepare chroot envirement
sudo mount -t proc /proc /mnt/proc;
sudo mount -t sysfs /sys /mnt/sys;
sudo mount --rbind /dev /mnt/dev;
sudo cp -f /etc/hosts /mnt/etc/;
sudo cp -f /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf;
sudo chroot /mnt rm /etc/mtab 2> /dev/null ;
sudo chroot /mnt ln -s /proc/mounts /etc/mtab ;
# get SSD path by UUID , probably it's /dev/sdb 
grub_install_target="$(sudo chroot /mnt blkid |grep "${newUUID}"|awk -F: '{print $1}')";
grub_install_target="${grub_install_target:0:8}";
((${#grub_install_target})) || echo you cannot continue;
# install grub and update it
sudo chroot /mnt grub-install "${grub_install_target}";
sudo chroot /mnt update-grub;
# unmount SSD before unluging it 
sudo umount -fl /mnt;
```

when you boot new copy google about adding a swap file (optional)

but as it was told to you a fresh installation is super quick and fine , 
if you just cannot use usb think about grub-imageboot or grml-rescueboot,
you can boot an iso from your actual hard drive an install it to the new SSD .

good luck

Comment: Hi Jonah, Thanks for the reply I feel like it's going to be very helpful for me, however despite following it up with some research I still feel as though I only understand half of it and am too scared to try and implement it. Could you please add a bit of elaboration to the reasoning and clarify the steps?I only have a very basic understanding of what GRUB or chroot are. Is the mount --bind of root /somewhere/ just arbitrary and the /elsewhere/ the new drive? If so, why the need?  An fictitious example would be great. Thanks heaps

Comment: P.S the contents of my fstab file: # Pluggable devices are handled by uDev, they are not in fstab
UUID=6e92d1d9-ca30-42d9-9e14-c749d0f349b5 / ext4 defaults 1 1
UUID=f6fa5d86-ca03-41b8-b59e-ce427520787a swap swap defaults 0 0 
Does that effect your while-do loop?

Comment: yes i'll update the answer with more details, but it'll be better if you tell how you wanna use the new copy : do you wanna replace your actual hard drive ? do you wanna keep both on same machine as multiboot? cause diffrent way for each case!

Comment: Hi Jonah, I'm really impressed with your reply, thank you. I don't know much about file systems, but why did we create an MBR instead of a GPT? And why did we have to make a blind mount of the root to /mnt? Admittedly I didn't mkdir sdb1, I just mounted /dev/sdb1 straight into /media. But this shouldn't matter should it? Anyway, I don't think the UUID actually worked. This is what it says:

Comment: ...It says: $ blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="rootMX19" UUID="6e92d1d9-ca30-42d9-9e14-c749d0f349b5" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="31d3ad8c-01"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="swapMX" UUID="f6fa5d86-ca03-41b8-b59e-ce427520787a" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="31d3ad8c-02"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="89aacba3-0311-4fe7-aff5-7a0e137c2e54" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="5e432ae4-01"
They are still different. Is it the PARTUUID that matters? Why does it need to change at all? Sorry about all the questions. Thank you very much!

Comment: mbr : because i saw your fstab content it does't contain EFI partition , gpt goes with efi system , and mbr goe's with legacy systems!
bindibg root mountPoint / to /mnt in order to be able to copy its content without errors and you won't have to exclude any,
mounting to /mnt or anywhere doesn't matter,
changing UUID in new copy's fstab to make it able to boot , else it'll just point to the old installation!
you don't need any gpt while you're using legacy boot!!.
anyhow it's not good to fill this section with comments , a bit later i'll update the answer to fit diffrent cases

Comment: Sorry about all the comments, I'm new to stackspace (and BASH). I forgot to answer you previously: its to create a copy of the OS for another PC. Could the reason the UUID didn't change be because I pasted it in the terminal, rather than running as a script? Similarly, (granted I don't understand what 'read f' is reading) but shouldn't 'sudo grep -rl "${oldUUID}" /mnt/{etc,boot}' search for the newUUID instead of the old? On a separate topic: So can I not use EFI/gpt because of the SSD hardware of this particular drive? Much appreciated Thanks again!

Comment: All the UUIDs are definitely changed on the drive. I manually checked. I'm wondering if the issue is by running sudo update-grub; did I need to do something with chroot, as you previously said? Cheers

Comment: update-grub will just add new os to your grub menu fro current pc, but you wish to use on other pc , just plug it and try booting it if not working, then you'll need chroot'ing , NOTE that by copying installed os from pc to different one you may encounter drivers problems .
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot

Comment: I'm really sorry for being such a novice, thanks for your patience. This is where I'm at: sudo chroot /mnt
root@Rob:/# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release: 10
Codename: buster
root@Rob:/# sudo update-grub;
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?).
Are you able to shed any light on the cause? Please and thank you!

Comment: Thanks so much Jonah, you are obviously a very experienced and talented user. I have learnt a lot from your answer, even improved my BASH. I should point out for others that you accidentally wrote sudo grub-update; instead of update-grub, twice. Speaking of, I had to boot through the grub recovery and run MX Boot, to repair. But your method did work. Thanks again

Comment: i'm glad you solved the issue , yes that was accidentally , i'll correct it .

Comment: Hi Jonah, long time, but I watched this great video today: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0kp_WtdoVCQ    and I was reminded of your efforts in this thread above. As you're the expert could you please comment on what you think of his method compared to your method? I would really appreciate it, because it seems to deliver a similar result, but with much less steps. Thank you!

Comment: (I do acknowledge that your solution would work for sda discs bigger than sdb discs)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your system is on **sda** and your new drive is **sdb** having enough capacity,
I would suggest you to consider using dd to get a functionally identical copy of your OS:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=128M
```

you may want adjust `bs` (block size) paramteter depending on your disk size/preferences.
Just be careful to not confuse: `if` is for source `of` is for destination

Once the copy is completed, the sdb disk can be used right away after you change you BIOS/EFI settings to boot from the sdb - you'll have to identify it there first.

Comment: Hi Tagwint, I used dd and it worked! Very easy method, thanks I like it. Where can I learn about what is a suitable 'bs=...'?

Comment: Right reference would me `man dd`, but considering you are newbie to that, you can start with other's answers like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27772496/439650

Comment: if sda bigger than sdb and contains gpt you won't have a working copy!
if sda smaller than sdb it will make sdb size same as sda size and hides remaining free space!
dd clonning is perfect for same sized disks or it'll need more workarounds.

Comment: Hi Jonah/Tagwint, so Tagwint, there is no best default but you recommended 128mb, yet the rule-of-thumb that person gave was 64kb? That's a big difference, is it a trade-off between speed and disk space consumption efficiency? Jonah, so you wold only recommend using dd if two SSDs are the same size? If sdb is bigger then can you not access the remaining hidden space at all?

Comment: @1toneboy, I think now it is time for you to do some research yourself and show your effort, there are ways of getting the hidden space back or limit the dd scope of copying in advance. These would be another questions i guess, we should not transform this comment chain to a tutorial,  should we ? :)
Here some start point for you to start your way:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475177/clone-a-hard-disk-using-dd-from-a-smaller-hard-disk-to-a-larger-disk